# Delete duplicate keys from an array of javascript objects based on keys present in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var toRemove = [
  "amount_after_regular_discount",
  "amount_after_to",
  "amount_after_activ_disc",
  "amount_after_activ_plus_disc",
  "total_advance_tax",
  "amount_after_special_discount",
  "amount_after_discount",
];
var items = [
  {
    zone: "North",
    unique_customers: "90",
    total_customers: "90",
    orders: "90",
    total_of_item_purchased_price: "429432.13",
    amount_without_discount: "415632.13",
    amount_after_to: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_disc: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_plus_disc: "378418.72",
    total_gst: "0.00",
    total_advance_tax: "0.00",
    amount_after_discount: "378418.72",
    amount_after_tax: "378418.72",
    sale_date: "2021-09-01",
  },
  {
    zone: "North",
    unique_customers: "90",
    total_customers: "90",
    orders: "90",
    total_of_item_purchased_price: "429432.13",
    amount_without_discount: "415632.13",
    amount_after_to: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_disc: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_plus_disc: "378418.72",
    total_gst: "0.00",
    total_advance_tax: "0.00",
    amount_after_discount: "378418.72",
    amount_after_tax: "378418.72",
    sale_date: "2021-09-01",
  },
];
```

I want to remove all keys included in the array `toRemove` from the `items` array of objects. so I want to get the resulted array of objects without all keys that are included in `toRemove` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var toRemove = [
  "amount_after_regular_discount",
  "amount_after_to",
  "amount_after_activ_disc",
  "amount_after_activ_plus_disc",
  "total_advance_tax",
  "amount_after_special_discount",
  "amount_after_discount",
];

var items = [
  {
    zone: "North",
    unique_customers: "90",
    total_customers: "90",
    orders: "90",
    total_of_item_purchased_price: "429432.13",
    amount_without_discount: "415632.13",
    amount_after_to: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_disc: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_plus_disc: "378418.72",
    total_gst: "0.00",
    total_advance_tax: "0.00",
    amount_after_discount: "378418.72",
    amount_after_tax: "378418.72",
    sale_date: "2021-09-01",
  },
  {
    zone: "North",
    unique_customers: "90",
    total_customers: "90",
    orders: "90",
    total_of_item_purchased_price: "429432.13",
    amount_without_discount: "415632.13",
    amount_after_to: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_disc: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_plus_disc: "378418.72",
    total_gst: "0.00",
    total_advance_tax: "0.00",
    amount_after_discount: "378418.72",
    amount_after_tax: "378418.72",
    sale_date: "2021-09-01",
  },
];

items.forEach((item) => Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => toRemove.includes(key) && delete item[key]))

console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to it with 2 loops ([map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) & [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), in my case) :

```js
const toRemove = [
  "amount_after_regular_discount",
  "amount_after_to",
  "amount_after_activ_disc",
  "amount_after_activ_plus_disc",
  "total_advance_tax",
  "amount_after_special_discount",
  "amount_after_discount"
];

const items = [
  {
    zone: "North",
    unique_customers: "90",
    total_customers: "90",
    orders: "90",
    total_of_item_purchased_price: "429432.13",
    amount_without_discount: "415632.13",
    amount_after_to: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_disc: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_plus_disc: "378418.72",
    total_gst: "0.00",
    total_advance_tax: "0.00",
    amount_after_discount: "378418.72",
    amount_after_tax: "378418.72",
    sale_date: "2021-09-01"
  },
  {
    zone: "North",
    unique_customers: "90",
    total_customers: "90",
    orders: "90",
    total_of_item_purchased_price: "429432.13",
    amount_without_discount: "415632.13",
    amount_after_to: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_disc: "378418.72",
    amount_after_activ_plus_disc: "378418.72",
    total_gst: "0.00",
    total_advance_tax: "0.00",
    amount_after_discount: "378418.72",
    amount_after_tax: "378418.72",
    sale_date: "2021-09-01"
  }
];

const stripped = items.map(x => {
  for (let i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
    const key = toRemove[i];
    delete x[key]
  }

  return x
})

console.log(stripped)
```